# Output A List of final positions

Tags: endgame

I have a .pgn database. I like to extract all of the final positions into a new pgn database. I do not have ay programming skills. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use my free [pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/%7Edjb/pgn-extract/) program with the `-F` flag to output the final position as a FEN string in a comment at the end of the game. If you don't want to include the moves then `--dropply -1` will omit all but the final move of the game in the output. For instance:

```
pgn-extract -F --dropafter -1 games.pgn
```

> [Event "Milwaukee Northwestern"] [Site "?"] [Date "1957"] [Round "?"]
> [White "Fischer, Robert J."] [Black "Kampars, N."] [Result "1/2-1/2"]
> [SetUp "1"] [FEN "8/pp4p1/3nk2p/2p2p2/5P2/2P1K1PP/PP2B3/8 w - - 2 37"]
>
> 37. Bd3 { "8/pp4p1/3nk2p/2p2p2/5P2/2PBK1PP/PP6/8 b - - 3 37" } 1/2-1/2